# What is use of declare(strict_types=1) in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-coding-standard

Why core file use this declare(strict_types=1) ?

Comment: Good explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48723830/5937931. As for why in M2 core i would love to hear an explanation from someone close to the team.

Comment: have you check https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/coding-standards/technical-guidelines.html

Comment: *Basic programming principles*: ` All new PHP files MUST have strict type mode enabled by starting wit: h declare(strict_types=1);. All updated PHP files SHOULD have strict type mode enabled. PHP interfaces MAY have this declaration`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Rule**

All new PHP files MUST have strict type mode enabled by starting with declare(strict_types=1);. All updated PHP files SHOULD have strict type mode enabled. PHP interfaces SHOULD NOT have this declaration.

**Reason**

Source: [Magento Technical Guidelines.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/technical-guidelines.html)

With PHP 7, it is possible to add type hinting to your code. However, this doesn't mean that types are actually enforced, unless strict typing is enabled by adding declare(strict_types=1) to the top of each PHP file.

PHP code becomes more robust when type hinting (argument types, return types) are added. With the declare(strict_types=1) added, there is less chance for bugs that related to type casting.